# Slurm jobs queued but not running

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to install slurm on Virtualbox running Ubuntu. We're using it to run long-running jobs via a web interface and we use slurm to queue and run the jobs. I'm using VirtualBox to create a sandbox for development.

I've set slurm up, but when I queue a job and run squeue I get:

```
$ squeue
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
                 2     debug  test.sh pchandle PD       0:00      1 (Nodes required for job are DOWN, DRAINED or reserved for jobs in higher priority partitions)
```

When I run it on my actual hardware, the jobs run successfully.

The output of sinfo is:

```
$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      0    n/a
```

Yes, it says nodes are 0, but the output is the same on my actual hardware, and jobs run fine. Any suggestions on why it's saying 0 nodes?

Is this an issue with my setup, or is simply not possible to run slurm on VirtualBox due to the hardware limitations? I'm running 4 CPUs. The only obvious difference I can see is that threads per core is only 1 (there are 2 on my local hardware).

Is there anyway to debug why the nodes aren't running jobs? Or why there are no nodes available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a configuration error.

In the config file /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf, I'd left the configuration NodeName as the default NodeName=localhost[0-31]. Since I am running on a single host it should have been set to NodeName=localhost for a single node on the same machine.

[Slurm Single Instance](https://blog.llandsmeer.com/tech/2020/03/02/slurm-single-instance.html) had a description of what the values should be set to, which helped me find the answer.

[Install Slurm on a stand alone Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/ckandoth/2acef6310041244a690e4c08d2610423) had the instructions I originally followed.